# apache redirect question

Tags: apache, redirect

## What I want to do is no matter what the user types in, redirect to index.php.

## Is this what I am saying here?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $0 !=index.php

RewriteRule .* index.php?path=$0 [QSA,B]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, this is the relevant code for rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,B,L]
```